# windows phone 8 xaml not getting updated

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Has anyone faced this issue? I've tried recreating the entire solution, checking that all the build action & copy to output settings, etc. The only way i can update the xaml now is by uninstalling the app, and redeploying every time.

Comment: is there an error `Deployment optimization failed with error 1000`

Comment: no there's no such errors, but what would you do if there's such error?

Comment: Does "Rebuild soulution" work as well? Build is not working but Rebuild does. Anyway, it's really annoying.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going to the folder of the source code and removed the 'read-only'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, a resx file downloaded from a translation service needed to get "unblocked" first

Comment: What do you mean by unblock? I just deleted all resx files, but it made no difference.

Comment: downloaded files are sometimes blocked on windows, and you have to go to properties and unblock.



If you do Clean before building, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

The .*.resx file Access Modifier might be set to

```
No code generation
```

try setting it to

```
public
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning and rebuilding solution worked for me.